# what does the following single code line mean in flash

Tags: flash

var so = new SWFObject("zoom.swf", "sotester", "1200", "600", "9", "#FFFFFF");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWFObject is a popular JavaScript script that instantiates Flash movies using JavaScipt. So, if this is inside a Flash movie, it is probably referencing the JavaScript in the host web page.

The arguments are:

```
* swf – The file path and name to your swf file.
* id – The ID of your object or embed tag. The embed tag will also have this value set as it’s name attribute for files that take advantage of swliveconnect.
* width – The width of your Flash movie.
* height – The height of your Flash movie.
* version – The required player version for your Flash content. This can be a string in the format of ‘majorVersion.minorVersion.revision’. An example would be: "6.0.65". Or you can just require the major version, such as "6".
* background-color – This is the hex value of the background color of your Flash movie.
```

More can be found here: http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/